# Does Windows Phone App Store give a way to contact developer?

Tags: apps, store

I can't see any documentation/contact-us information on an app I bought - just the information on the main app page. Isn't this standard app-store functionality, so people can report bugs?

Other than leave a review, I see no way to ask a question about a feature or submit a bug report. Which seems pretty poor. Am I missing something or does MS not require any of that stuff from developers?

(the app is http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/recorder-p-ro/531c806d-bba8-445c-bd54-f83845c146fa#)

Answer (score 3):

The only way to contact a developer is by giving a review (which, by the way, is not necessarily a bad option), or if the app has an option to contact the developer.

Comment: Indeed. Microsoft has added a feature recently that the developer can actually respond to you if you leave a review.